# How to avoid duplicate key error in mysql

Tags: mysql, concurrency, insert, duplicates, locking

I have a problem to get a next sequence id in my code. Though it was a legacy code i have to follow the same. Let me explain the logic which was followed.

```
CREATE TABLE `emp_seq` (
  `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=INNODB AUTO_INCREMENT=1234 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Above table used to get the next sequence id for the below table. and also `emp_seq` table will have only one entry for the id.

```
CREATE TABLE `emp_info` (
  `id` BIGINT(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(128) DEFAULT '',
  `active` TINYINT(2) DEFAULT '1',
`level` MEDIUMINT(8) DEFAULT '100',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `level` (`level`)
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='employee information'
```

so whenever we trying to insert a new record to emp_info table, we are getting next sequence id from the table emp_seq by using below queries.

```
INSERT INTO emp_seq () VALUES ();
DELETE FROM emp_seq WHERE id < LAST_INSERT_ID;
```

Now the problem is, some times because of multiple asynchronous calls in the application, the same increment id has been shared to multiple records and trying to insert in the emp_info table and we are getting below error

```
"code":"ER_DUP_ENTRY","errno":1062,"sqlMessage":"Duplicate entry 1234 for key
```

Kindly help me how to resolve the issue.

Comment: *the same increment id has been shared to multiple records and trying to insert in the emp_info table and we are getting below error* This is absolutely impossible. Show the code which retrieves the value to be used during the insertion into `emp_info` and the code which inserts.

Comment: *`DELETE FROM emp_seq WHERE id < LAST_INSERT_ID;`* is errorneous and must produce an error "Unknown column 'LAST_INSERT_ID' in 'where clause'".

Comment: @LAST_INSERT_ID - I have taken it from last insert id method. For understanding purpose i put it like that.

Comment: the same increment id has been shared to multiple records and trying to insert in the emp_info table and we are getting below error This is absolutely impossible. - It is happening actually. Before insert into emp_info table,  we have called the insert and delete queries and it returns the auto increment id, that id used to insert in the emp_info table @Akina

Comment: Show complete code, not a part of it. You obviously do something wrongly. AI cannot return the same value to 2 concurrent threads.